# reverse effect of explode function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In scala with spark-2.4, I would like to filter the value inside the arrays in a column.

From

```
+---+------------+
| id|      letter|
+---+------------+
|  1|[x, xxx, xx]|
|  2|[yy, y, yyy]|
+---+------------+
```

To

```
+---+-------+
| id| letter|
+---+-------+
|  1|[x, xx]|
|  2|[yy, y]|
+---+-------+
```

I thought of using `explode` + `filter`

```
val res = Seq(("1", Array("x", "xxx", "xx")), ("2", Array("yy", "y", "yyy"))).toDF("id", "letter")
res.withColumn("tmp", explode(col("letter"))).filter(length(col("tmp")) < 3).drop(col("letter")).show()
```

And I'm getting

```
+---+---+
| id|tmp|
+---+---+
|  1|  x|
|  1| xx|
|  2| yy|
|  2|  y|
+---+---+
```

How do I zip/groupBy back by id ?

Or maybe there is a better, more optimised solution ?

Answer (score 6):

You can filter the array without `explode()` in Spark 2.4:

```
res.withColumn("letter", expr("filter(letter, x -> length(x) < 3)")).show()
```

Output:

```
+---+-------+
| id| letter|
+---+-------+
|  1|[x, xx]|
|  2|[yy, y]|
+---+-------+
```

Answer (score 2):

In Spark 2.4+, higher order functions are the way to go (`filter`), alternatively use `collect_list` :

```
res.withColumn("tmp",explode(col("letter")))
  .filter(length(col("tmp")) < 3)
  .drop(col("letter"))
  // aggregate back
  .groupBy($"id")
  .agg(collect_list($"tmp").as("letter"))
  .show()
```

gives:

```
+---+-------+
| id| letter|
+---+-------+
|  1|[x, xx]|
|  2|[yy, y]|
+---+-------+
```

As this introduces a shuffle, it's better to use UDF for that:

```
def filter_arr(maxLength:Int)= udf((arr:Seq[String]) => arr.filter(str => str.size<=maxLength))

res
  .select($"id",filter_arr(maxLength = 2)($"letter").as("letter"))
  .show()
```

gives:

```
+---+-------+
| id| letter|
+---+-------+
|  1|[x, xx]|
|  2|[yy, y]|
+---+-------+
```